# Work Books Sheets copy to Multiple WorkBooks and Rename

Tags: excel, vba

I have workbook and there many sheets i want to copy one by one sheets to new work book and rename workbook

I tried, but it saved in one workbook instead of separate workbooks also I don't want to copy first worksheet to copy new workbook

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateWorkBooks()
    Dim ws As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws_num As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = Worksheets
    ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For i = 2 To ws_num
        'Copy one worksheet as a new workbook
        'The new workbook becomes the ActiveWorkbook
        ws.Copy

        'Replace all formulas with values (optional)
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value

        'May want (not required) to add a file name extension (.xls or .xlsx) to the file name
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
          "AR Balance- " & ActiveSheet.Name & " " & Worksheets("DATA Sheet").Range("m2") & ".xlsx"
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False 
    Next 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Only simple self explanatory corrections made. Try

```
 Option Explicit
Sub CreateWorkBooks()
    Dim ws As Worksheet  ' Worksheets instead of Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws_num As Integer
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For i = 2 To ws_num
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)      'set ws to each sheet in the workbook
        'Copy one worksheet as a new workbook
        'The new workbook becomes the ActiveWorkbook
        ws.Copy

        'Replace all formulas with values (optional)
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value

        'May want (not required) to add a file name extension (.xls or .xlsx) to the file name
        ' Thisworkbook  is to be added to refer Worksheets("DATA Sheet").Range("m2").Value
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
          "AR Balance- " & ActiveSheet.Name & " " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA Sheet").Range("m2").Value & ".xlsx"

        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It didn't work, nothing happened when run code it go to For i = 2 To ws_num then Jump to Sub End Could you help

Comment: It is tried out code. and working perfectly. Please go to `ThisWorkbook.Path` and check for new files created. Alternately run the code for second time it will overwrite msgbox will popup  for each sheet.

Comment: it may not work, if workbook does not have more than one visible sheet..Also  may gives error if run from unsaved new excel file with out a sheet named `DATA Sheet` or cell m2 and sheet names have illegal file name chars.